# Caching response for API.ai Node.js webhook

Tags: node.js, caching, node-modules, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a webhook designed in Node.js for API.ai that interacts with multiple API's to gather information and give response to user.

Since, I am interacting with multiple API's the response time taken is more than 5 secs which is causing the API.ai request to timeout.

To overcome this, I am trying to implement caching into the node.js webhook which saves the response from API's until a certain amount of time. This will remove timeout until the max-age header time is reached.

Edit: What is the best node module that I can use to cache the API responses for subsequest requests.

Note: I am using [request node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for http requests but it doesnt seem to provide a way to cache the response.

Comment: It's not clear as to what you want from StackOverflow.

Comment: Edited the question :-) . Hope its clear now.

Comment: If you have mongodb on your server you can use this module I made a while back: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wp-node  You can pass a TTL to the .cache method or define it globally.

Comment: Sorry. Not using MongoDB. :-(

Comment: You should look into some in-memory database like redis or memcached for this.

Comment: I used in the past: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache and it was working well... Give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to use the below module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache

This served my scenario better. Might try using Redis soon when i get some time.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers given are reasonable for tackling the cache problem on the request side. But since you specified API.AI and Actions, you might also be able to, or need to, store information while the conversation is in progress. You can do this using an API.AI context.

It may even be that if you limit it to just one remote call for each response from the user, you might be able to fit it in the timeframe.

For example, if you were having a conversation about movie times and ticket ordering, the conversation may go something like:

> User: "I want to see a movie."
>
> [You use an API to lookup the nearest theater, store the theater's location in a context and reply] "Your nearest theater is the Mall Megaplex. Are you interested in one there?"
>
> User: "Sure"
>
> [You now already have the theater, so you query for what it is playing with another API call and store it in a context] "There are seven different movies playing, including Star Wars and Jaws. Do those sound interesting?"
>
> User: "No"
>
> [You already have the data in the context, so you don't need another call.] "How about Rocky or..."

In this way you're making the same number of calls (generally), but storing the user's results in the session as you go as opposed to collecting all the information for the user, or all the possible results, and then narrowing them.